# Getting files from S3, putting them in heroku /tmp folder, unzipping and uploading back to s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3

I'm developing an app that attempts to do the following:

1. gets zip files from amazon s3
2. puts them in the heroku #{Rails.root}/tmp folder
3. unzips files
4. upload them back to s3
5. deletes temporary files

Everything works if I run the app locally, but when I try to run the app on heroku, it just doesn't work. The script runs and gives me no error but the files are not transferred to the tmp folder.

Do I need to do something different to store files in the heroku tmp folder? Is the Process.pid required in filenames?

I'm using AWS::S3::S3Object.url_for to generate temporary urls to get the files from s3

i'm using the following code to get the files:

```
Net::HTTP.start("s3.amazonaws.com") { |http|
    resp = http.get(file_path)
    open("#{Rails.root}/tmp/files/#{tmp_save_path}", "wb") { |file|
        file.write(resp.body)
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you have more to the snippet, my guess is that the directory "#{Rails.root}/tmp/files/..." does not exist on Heroku (this should be raising: `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory`). Try using `mkdir_p` to create it before every call (remember Heroku will clear out tmp). You will need to parse out the folder from the path (see [file utilities](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/index.html)).

Comment: Apparently, I did need to add the Process.pid to the temp path like: "#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{Process.pid}_files/" Thanks for your help!